# Update SymbolLayer iconImageName with zoom level on Mapbox iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

*Platform: iOS*

*Mapbox SDK version: 4.0.0*

How can I update `iconImageName` in latest version?

In older verson, I was using following code:

```
symbolLayer.iconImageName = [MGLStyleValue valueWithInterpolationMode:MGLInterpolationModeInterval
      cameraStops:@{
                    @8: [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:imageNameOne],
                    @10: [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:imageNameTwo]                            }
          options: nil];
```

But in version `4.0.0`, I tried with this code:

```
    NSDictionary *cameraStops = @{
                              @8: [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:imageNameOne],
                              @10: [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:imageNameTwo]
                            };

symbolLayer.iconImageName = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"mgl_interpolate:withCurveType:parameters:stops:($zoomLevel, 'interval', nil, %@)", cameraStops];
```

But getting error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid property value: [1][0]:
>   Unknown interpolation type interval'.

Answer (score 3):

The curve type argument for `mgl_interpolate:withCurveType:parameters:stops:` takes 3 main arguments: `linear`, `exponential`, and `cubicBezier`. Does something like this work?

```
   NSDictionary *cameraStops = @{
                          @8: imageNameOne,
                          @10: imageNameTwo
                        };
   symbolLayer.iconImageName = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"mgl_step:from:stops:($zoomLevel, nil, %@)", cameraStops];
```

You may also find this [migration guide](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.0.0/migrating-to-expressions.html) helpful when updating your code.

Comment: With expressions, the old “interval” interpolation mode corresponds to a step expression, rather than an interpolate expression, because values between the stops (such as 9 in the original example) aren’t actually interpolated. However, interpolation is generally better than stepping when working with zoom levels, because the user can zoom to fractional zoom levels.